# Static files are missing after deploying Magento 2 in production mode

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

I'm using "push to deploy" method to deploy Magento 2 app with GIT.

After pushing to master following commands are executed on the production server:

```
git checkout master && git pull origin master
composer install
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

After this, some static files have status code 404. Looks like they are not generated.

For example:

```
ls -l pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/xxxxx/sl_SI/mage/requirejs/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 magento magento 70 Jun 23 17:21 mixins.js -> /home/magento/www.xxxxx.si/public/lib/web/mage/requirejs/mixins.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 magento magento 72 Jun 23 17:21 resolver.js -> /home/magento/www.xxxxx.si/public/lib/web/mage/requirejs/resolver.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 magento magento 68 Jun 23 17:21 text.js -> /home/magento/www.xxxxx.si/public/lib/web/mage/requirejs/text.js
```

I have deleted all folders, tried all commands for di:compile and deploy all over again, cleared cache, etc. Looks like nothing else works other than changing deploy mode to developer and then back to production.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

After this files like pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/xxxxx/sl_SI/mage/requirejs/mixins.js are back in the folder.

There must be something that I'm missing... Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should run deploy command with your locale.

Run below command..

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy sl_SI -f